# Adding names to authorized IP addresses of SQL instance in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using a bash script to set up a VM instance on GCP. Later the ephemeral IP address is promoted to static by the script. Now I wish to add this IP address as one of the authorized addresses for a sql server using CLI.

I am able to do this from the GUI console(i.e. providing the IP address as well as an optional name). However, I wish to do this completely using CLI.

I have tried using `gcloud sql instances patch $SQL --authorized-networks=$NEWPOOL --quiet` where $SQL is my SQL instance name and $NEWPOOL is the string containing all the authorized IPs. This 'whitelists' the addresses, however I am unable to set the name for each IP. I am unable to find it in the documentation also.

I need a code which would help me set the name of the IP addresses from CLI.

Comment: The Google Cloud SDK CLI does not have an option to name a network. The API does. You will need to write a command in your favorite language.

Comment: Can you give an example please. I need to save all the previous IPs along with the new one with its name.

Comment: You will need to write this program.